# execute bash on Network Location profile change

Tags: bash, proxy, automator

I have a Macbook I use to work both at my office and at home. Due to my enterprise's policies, I have to navigate through proxy. **I created two newtwork profiles** (home, office) in which I set proxy and credentials I have to use.

However, there are several applications for which I have to manually edit configuration in order to have them work with proxy (git, npm, and a bunch of others). **I also created two bash files that set/unset config key at convenience**.

Question is: **can I "listen" to an event such as network profile change, in order to run appropriate bash script, depending on selected location?**

Maybe Automator can help?